# How to get a list of days of the range?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
id | from_date | to_date
---------------------------------------------
1 | 2015-11-03 00:00:00 | 2015-11-05 23:59:59
2 | 2015-11-07 00:00:00 | 2015-11-07 23:59:59
```

I need to get the following:

```
2015-11-03
2015-11-04
2015-11-05
2015-11-07
```

Comment: why not 2015-11-06? what is the pattern? also what have you tried?

Comment: Yeah, as the question stands, one needs magic skills to give you an answer!

Comment: Days between from and to, I suppose. The first range is between 3 and 5, the 2nd is 7 to 7, therefore 6 is missing.

Comment: However, either the OP needs a stored procedure or a helper table with all possible dates to do this in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a tally table:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(from_date, INTERVAL rn DAY) AS `date`
FROM mytable
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT 1 AS n1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
    ) AS t1 CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 1 AS n2 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
    ) AS t2
  ) AS t CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := -1) AS var   
) AS tally ON DATEDIFF(to_date, from_date) >= rn
ORDER BY `date`
```

The above query assumes that consecutive `[from_date, to_date]` intervals are *not* overlapping.

The tally table used is the result of a `CROSS JOIN` between two in-line tables of 10 rows each, hence it has exactly 100 rows. You may need a bigger table if your data contains `[from_date, to_date]` intervals which are larger than 100 days.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5094/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using date_format() function:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fromDate,'%Y-%m-%d') AS FromDate FROM tablename;
```

**Output:**

FromDate
2015-11-03
2015-11-04
2015-11-05
2015-11-07